# Finding the last row with data using vba

Tags: vba, excel, row

**I am creating a program in which everytime it generates, the generated data will appear in a specific sheet and arranged in specific date order . It looks like this.**

[image: Generated data]

But when I generate again, the existing data will be replaced/covered by the new data generated. Looks like this.

[image]

Now my idea is, before I am going to paste another data, I want to find out first what is the last used cell with value so that in the next generation of data, it wont be replaced/covered by the new one. Can someone help me with this. The output should look like this.

[image]

Any help everyone? Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your question is "Don't overwrite the second column of data" - but of course that ignores the information you haven't provided. If you want a good answer, you will need to provide details on how your data is generated (e.g. what is the code). Then we can help you with how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 3):

As per your case try with below code

```
Dim lastcolumn as Long
lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
```

Comment: kindly mark it as solution if it works

Answer (score 0):

This will assign the value of the last Row (as Integer) to the variable 'lastRow'

`Dim lastRow as Integer
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) _
, , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row`

You could also remove the '.row' at the end of the statement and set it to a range-variable. Then you have more information about where the last row is, but I think in your case it is enough just to know in which row (as Integer) the last used cell is.

If you need the last Column, just replace '.row' at the end of the statement with '.Column'.

**EDIT:** You also could use `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` but i don't like this way, because it don't give you the right result all the time (don't know why, but often had this problem).